# Emacs. read and write file of another user account on same machine

Tags: emacs

I have two users ( rajiv which is default ) and hduser(hduser is not in the sudoers file) on my machine.

How do I read/write the files in account hduser from my emacs in user rajiv?

Currently, when I switch to hduser in the terminal and open the file /home/hduser/.bashrc via pico,I can edit the file. But it opens in read-only mode from my emacs in user rajiv

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use Emacs' ["remote file"](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Remote-Files.html) capability (which is via the Ange-FTP or Tramp packages).  You would do it like so:

```
C-x C-f /hduser@localhost:/home/hduser/.bashrc RET
```